# Apache Spark connector to read from Azure Queue service?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, apache-spark-2.0

This can be more of a configuration question, but could not find a specific answer to the problem I am trying to solve.

I am looking for a connector to read from [Azure Storage Queue Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/storage/?v=16.50) through Spark, though there are connectors available for Azure Blob storage. Want to confirm if there is a connector to read from Azure Storage Queue or somebody have solved the problem before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@jdk2588, there isn't a specific connector from Azure Storage Queue Service via Spark specifically, however you should consider the use of process workflows: "Azure Queue storage provides cloud messaging between application components. Queue storage also supports managing asynchronous tasks and building process work flows." More details can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azurequeues/

Comment: I have a similar question poster [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72062529/1232087) and I was wondering if you would have time to share your thoughts. Thank you.