# How to use Azure Key Vault in Apache Spark Connector for SQL Server

Tags: apache-spark, azure-sql-database, azure-databricks, azure-keyvault, azure-synapse

Following example from Azure team on [Using Apache Spark connector for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/spark/connector?view=sql-server-ver15) is using hard-coded user name and password. But I am storing password in [Azure key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/overview) for security requirements.

**Question**: In the following example code, instead of using hard-coded password, how can we use a secret (password) stored in an Azure Key Vault? For example, suppose I have created Azure Key Vault secret call `mySQLSecret` with a value `myPassword`. How would I use `mySQLSecret` in the code below?

```java
    server_name = "jdbc:sqlserver://{SERVER_ADDR}"
    database_name = "database_name"
    url = server_name + ";" + "databaseName=" + database_name + ";"
    
    table_name = "table_name"
    username = "username"
    password = "password123!#" # Please specify password here
    
    try:
      df.write \
        .format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark") \
        .mode("overwrite") \
        .option("url", url) \
        .option("dbtable", table_name) \
        .option("user", username) \
        .option("password", password) \
        .save()
    except ValueError as error :
        print("Connector write failed", error)
```

Comment: Where do you run Spark? Databricks, synapse, or just VMs?

Comment: @AlexOtt I run it in `Databricks`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to link azure keyvault as Databricks secret scope ([doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/secrets/secret-scopes#--create-an-azure-key-vault-backed-secret-scope)), and fetch a secret with password from it using the `dbutils.secrets.get` function. This function accepts two parameters - name of secret scope that you used to register when linking, and name of the secret inside keyvault