# Azure Databricks cluster spark configuration is disabled

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks

When creating an `Azure Databricks` and configuring its `cluster`, I had chosen the default languages for `Spark` to be `python,sql`. But now I want to add `Scala`, as well. When running the Scala script I was getting the following error. So, my online search took me to [this](https://sqlwithmanoj.com/2020/06/08/databricks-notebook-error-your-administrator-has-only-allowed-sql-and-scala-commands-on-this-cluster/) article that describes that you can change Cluster configuration by going to the `Advanced options` section of the cluster settings page and clicking on the `Spark` tab there (as shown in image below). But I find the Spark section there greyed out (disabled):

**Question**: How can I enabled the `Spark` section of the Advanced section of the cluster settings page (shown in image below) so I can edit the last line of the section? Note: I created the Databricks and its cluster and hence I am the admin (as shown in image 2 below).

> Databricks Notebook error: Your administrator has only allowed sql and python commands on this cluster.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to click "Edit" button in the cluster controls - after that you should be able to change Spark configuration.  But you can't enable Scala for the High concurrency clusters with credentials passthrough as it supports only Python & SQL ([doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/credential-passthrough/adls-passthrough#--enable-azure-data-lake-storage-credential-passthrough-for-a-high-concurrency-cluster)) - primary reason for that is that with Scala you can bypass users isolation.

If you need credentials passthrough + Scala, then you need to use Standard cluster, but it will work only with a single specific user ([doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/credential-passthrough/adls-passthrough#--enable-azure-data-lake-storage-credential-passthrough-for-a-standard-cluster)).

Comment: In the second sentence of your post above, did you mean `.....as it supports only Python and SQL`.

Comment: Your suggestion worked (thank you). I have another question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72062529/1232087) in case you have any suggestion/comments.

Comment: Yes. It should be SQL - fixed

Comment: Screw the edit button